# Pinterest won't recognize verification metatag

Tags: wordpress, meta-tags, pinterest

I'm trying to verify a website on Pinterest using a metatag:

`<meta name="p:domain_verify" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>`

The site is hosted on Wordpress

1) I added the metatag to the header inside `<head>`and tried to verify ---- didn't work
2) Then I tried to place it inside the  `<footer>` instead  ----- didn't work
3) I tried many different Wordpress plugins   ---- didn't work

I know the plugin did its job, when I look at the source code, the metatag is clearly there (in the head). Why is Pinterest not verifying it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try following the specific steps for Wordpress described by Pintrest:

- Copy the meta tag from Pinterest
- Go to your Wordpress blog dashboard
- Open the Tools -> Available Tools Page and paste the meta tag into the Pinterest Site Verification field
- Click on Save Changes
- Go back to pinterest.com/website/verify and click Complete Verification

In the *Get instructions for popular hosts* section of

https://help.pinterest.com/en/articles/verify-your-website

Comment: Thanks but I think that doesn't work if you have your own domain. Or maybe some other reason, but I don't have that on Available Tools. I only have Press This and Categories and Tags Converter..

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to Pinterest and click your name on the right side of your profile page.
2. Click the gear menu, and select edit account.
3. Now scroll down to where your website is listed and click on verify website.
4. Copy meta tag and paste it in your word processor i.e., Microsoft Word. Now copy only what is inside the parenthesis from your meta tag.
5. Now go to your website->All In One-> General Settings->scroll down 'til you find Pinterest and paste the meta tag there. Now update your page at the bottom of the page.
6. Go back to Pinterest (where you left off) click on verify website and now you will see the word verified!
   All done!
   Edward Mijarez